# Testing of useEffect hook with try/catch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I need to test a `catch` when the fetching data request rejects but I don't understand why the error is not being caught and I get this error:

> `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)`

I have a situation like this:

```js
export const Container = ({fetchFirstAsset, fetchSecondAsset}) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

  async function fetchAssets() {
    setStatus(IN_PROGRESS);

    try {
      await fetchFirstAsset();
      await fetchSecondAsset()

      setStatus(SUCCESS);
    } catch {
      setStatus(FAILURE);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAssets();
  }, []);

  ....
};
```

And I test like this:

```js
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const fetchFirstAsset = jest.fn();
const fetchSecondAsset = jest.fn();

it('should render without errors', async () => {
  fetchFirstAsset.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve());
  fetchSecondAsset.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.reject());
  let component;

  await act(async () => {
    component = mount(
      <Container
        fetchFirstAsset={fetchFirstAsset}
        fetchSecondAsset={fetchSecondAsset}
      />
    );
  });

  expect(fetchSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If I test the case when `fetchSomething` resolves with `Promise.resolve()` everything works fine and the tests pass, but when I try to `Promise.reject()` in order to test the `catch` case then this error is not caught and I have `unhandled promise rejection`.

(If you are wondering why code looks like this: In other places in the app I handle changing of status with redux, so testing of catch is easy, but in one place I need to fetch 3 different assets for the component and I decided to handle the change of status with `useState` because extracting 3 different statuses from redux and combining it will be ugly. With `useState` is much cleaner I think)

Thanks in advance for help! :)

Answer (score 5):

That's a good one,
You need to declare your function inside the `useEffect()` and implement the `try/catch` block inside of it, and outside of the function you only call it

(also, don't forget to cleanup your `useEffect()`)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAssets = async () => {
    setStatus(IN_PROGRESS);

    try {
      await fetchFirstAsset();
      await fetchSecondAsset()

      setStatus(SUCCESS);
    } catch {
      setStatus(FAILURE);
    }
  }

  fetchAssets();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem whereby the try/catch clause does not work when used within useEffect().  I did a few searches and it appears this is a potential bug, take a look at:

https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/305

*That said, I was able to address the issue as follows:*

**FAILURE EXAMPLE:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  try {
      invokeMyAsyncFunction();  
      setStatus(SUCCESS);
  } catch (e) {
      setStatus(FAILURE);   // <== will not be invoked on exception!!
  }
}
```

**SUCCESS EXAMPLE:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  invokeMyAsyncFunction()
     .then((response:any) => {
        setStatus(SUCCESS);
     })
     .catch((e) => {
        setStatus(FAILURE);   // <== this **WILL** be invoked on exception
     });
}
```

Comment: Decorate the `async` function with `await` and the try/catch should work as expected.  Otherwise the useEffect will not wait for the async functions to complete.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your catch block like this:

```
catch (e) {
     // can do something with e in here
      setStatus(FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: let me know if this helps or if you need any more help!

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not changing outcome, caling `catch` is the same as `catch (e)`
Maybe it's some kind of bug but I don't know if `mount` or `act` cannot handle this